# Best online source for learning C

Tags: c, objective-c, actionscript-3

Im an experienced actionscript developer, and relatively new to Objective C.

I decided a good investment of my time would be to master the C language (not C# or C++).

Can anyone recommend the 'best' online tutorials for learning C?

Comment: I'd recommend [a good introductory book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) over some web based resource just about any day.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books

Comment: Did you want to learn Obj-C too?

Comment: thanks for all the suggestions...will probably opt for the K&R book...just browsed a copy, not impressed by the poor printing..or the price but seems like a great reference. Yes , learning OBjective C.

Comment: Deitel and Deitel books have a pretty good reputation, also. You might track down any version of _C How to Program_, Deitel&Deitel, at the library.

Comment: https://hackr.io/tutorials/learn-c is a good place to find the best C programming tutorials submitted and voted by the programming community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't have difficulties understanding the C syntax given your past experience, and unfortunately, most tutorials and introductory books will focus on it much more than they should.

C is full of traps, but it is a simple language which gives you full control on what is going on with your programs. However, it is difficult to master. You will need something more elaborated than a simple tutorial which will be half full of things you probably already know.

I definitely recommand [K&R's book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language_(book)) if you want to learn the language correctly. Be sure to grab the second edition.

Comment: +1 K&R is the only way to learn C.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with James' comment, though I would recommend looking over the first paragraphs of a web based tutorial.

Though they're not the best for learning the language itself, you can get a feel for some trivial programs and see if they fit your brain.

The worst thing that can happen here is if you buy a book and can't use the language (for whatever reason).

As far as specific selections... I can't give you any.

Answer (score 0):

As you've asked for online resources only, so here is one

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson1.html

Like Alexandre , I would also recommend [K & R's](http://www.amazon.co.uk/C-Programming-Language-2nd/dp/0131103628) book

Answer (score 0):

You should check this out too:
http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/c_book/c_book/index.html

I've looked through it, it's got some good examples and it's a good read.